# Can openTelemetry instrumentation be used to track Kafka span propagation in any observability tool like Jaeger?

Tags: apache-kafka, jaeger, open-telemetry

Below is kafka call from 'spring-boot-client' app to 'spring-boot-server' app. Notice the reference type in the second screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Kafka span on the consumer side(spring-boot-server) is being tracked as FOLLOWS_FROM reference rather than CHILD_OF in Jaeger UI. So basically, I was able to backtrack Kafka spans but wasn't able to traverse forward (from client to server) in the UI.

Is there a way to track spans starting from client and then server, Can openTelemetry instrumentation be used to track Kafka span propagation in any observability tool like Jaeger ?

I also came across this open issue - https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-ui/issues/662